# Trying to extract images from .imb archives used by Railroad Tycoon 2

Tags: game

I am trying to extract the sprites from Railroad Tycoon 2. Having successfully extracted the files contained in the data .paks it uses, I am now stuck at trying to extract files from the .imb files it seems to use to store the sprites. There are also .pal files, I presume these are connected somehow.

I have uploaded a few of the .imb files here as an example: https://mega.nz/file/l3hxwADD#rcOwsQEUliZ3ypX95ZwW4BElLk5rPzrfr63QKXQ0dOA

Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Perhaps explain what you've already tried for the .imb and .pal files ?  Perhaps include hex dumps (in text, not image format) of any headers or other interesting parts of the .imb and .pal files?  (Many people won't download files of unclear provenance.)